# Neo4j Cypher query and complex sorting

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (t:Tenant) WHERE ID(t) in {tenantIds} 
 OR t.isPublic 
WITH COLLECT(t) as tenants 
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
 AND (not (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) 
   OR any(t in tenants WHERE (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t))) 
 AND (not (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) 
   OR any(t in tenants WHERE (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)))  
MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]-(filterValue630:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(filterCharacteristic630:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(filterCharacteristic630) = 630 
WITH filterValue630, childD, ru, u 
WHERE  (filterValue630.value <= 799621200000)  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue631:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic631:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(sortCharacteristic631) = 631 
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) 
 | {entityId: id(entity),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1:Criterion)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg1:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_FOR]->(childD) 
 | {criterionId: id(c1),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) 
 | {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics 
ORDER BY sortValue631.value ASC, childD.createDate DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

as a result of this query execution I receive 15 records where each of them correctly contains populated `commentGroups`, `weightedCriteria` and `valuedCharacteristics` collections.

But when I changing my query to the following one(I'm adding sort condition by criteria weight):

```
MATCH (t:Tenant) 
WHERE ID(t) in {tenantIds} 
 OR t.isPublic 
WITH COLLECT(t) as tenants 
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} 
 AND (not (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) 
  OR any(t in tenants WHERE (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t))) 
 AND (not (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) 
  OR any(t in tenants WHERE (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)))  
MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]-(filterValue630:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(filterCharacteristic630:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(filterCharacteristic630) = 630 
WITH filterValue630, childD, ru, u 
WHERE  (filterValue630.value <= 799621200000)  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} 
WITH c, childD, ru, u, (vg.avgVotesWeight * (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN coalesce({criteriaCoefficients}[toString(id(c))], 1.0) ELSE 1.0 END)) as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue631:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic631:Characteristic) 
WHERE id(sortCharacteristic631) = 631 
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes, sortValue631, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) 
 | {entityId: id(entity),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1:Criterion)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg1:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_FOR]->(childD) 
 | {criterionId: id(c1),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, 
[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) 
 | {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics 
ORDER BY  weight DESC,  totalVotes ASC, sortValue631.value ASC, childD.createDate DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

the query works without errors and returns the same result set of 15 records but `commentGroups`, `weightedCriteria` and `valuedCharacteristics` collections are only populated where `weight > 0` The rest of them are `null`

This is wrong and not as expected. The `commentGroups`, `weightedCriteria` and `valuedCharacteristics` collections should be populated for all records in my result set as it was after the first query execution.

Right now I don't understand why the following part of new Cypher query prevents correct population of the mentioned collections:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} 
WITH c, childD, ru, u, (vg.avgVotesWeight * (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN coalesce({criteriaCoefficients}[toString(id(c))], 1.0) ELSE 1.0 END)) as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes
```

What am I doing wrong within a new query and how to fix it?

**UPDATED**

This is the query which produces the issue:

```
MATCH (t:Tenant) WHERE ID(t) in [] 
  OR t.isPublic 
  WITH COLLECT(t) as tenants 
  MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) 
  WHERE id(parentD) = 60565 
    AND (not (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) 
      OR any(t in tenants WHERE (parentD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t))) 
    AND (not (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(:Tenant) 
      OR any(t in tenants WHERE (childD)-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t)))  
  MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]-(filterValue60639:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(filterCharacteristic60639:Characteristic) 
  WHERE id(filterCharacteristic60639) = 60639 
  WITH filterValue60639, childD, ru, u 
  WHERE  (filterValue60639.value <= 799621200000)  
  OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
  WHERE id(c) IN [60581, 60575] 
  WITH childD, ru, u, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight, vg.totalVotes as totalVotes 
  OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue60640:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic60640:Characteristic) 
  WHERE id(sortCharacteristic60640) = 60640 
  RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes, sortValue60640, 
  [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) 
    | {entityId: id(entity),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
  [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1:Criterion)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg1:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_FOR]->(childD) 
    | {criterionId: id(c1),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, 
  [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) 
    | {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics 
  ORDER BY  weight DESC,  totalVotes ASC, sortValue60640.value ASC, childD.createDate DESC 
  SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
```

for a some reason

```
  OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
  WHERE id(c) IN [60581, 60575]
```

prevents  `commentGroups`, `weightedCriteria` and `valuedCharacteristics` collection population for all `childD` that do not match this expression.. How to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: would be good if you can strip down the query further and provide a minimal dataset to demo it and share it via http://console.neo4j.org.

Comment: I can't find information how to dump the database to Cypher script under Windows platform in order to be loaded to console.neo4j.org

Comment: @StefanArmbruster I have updated my question with a dump of my test database. Unfortunately I don't find a way how to upload it to console.neo4j.org so I have dumped my database to filesystem.

Comment: I'm struggling with this query second day and don't understand how   `OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
  WHERE id(c) IN [60581, 60575]` impacts pattern comprehension like for example `[ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[rso:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[rsf:SET_FOR]->(childD) 
    | {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics` and how to fix it.

Comment: Your db in the dump is password protected, and the default neo4j/neo4j isn't working.

Comment: @InverseFalcon this is strange because I just restored my database from this dump and accessed without any passwords.. also I use dbms.security.auth_enabled=false at my local machine

Comment: Those credentials don't seem to be working either.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I just downloaded the latest version of Neo4j 3.1.1 Community Edition and successfully started this server locally on my dump without any passwords

Comment: I forgot that configuration for disabling auth isn't in the default.graphdb, I had to disable this in my own config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is a rather odd thing. I found something that should work, though at the moment I can't tell why it's working, just that it involves calculating weight and totalVotes before your return.

Take the first line of your RETURN, and replace it with this, which includes a WITH clause first, which will calculate the weight and totalVotes, then perform the RETURN:

```
WITH ru, u, childD, toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes, sortValue60640
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, weight, totalVotes, sortValue60640,
```

One other thing to note, you can save some unnecessary operations by performing your ORDER BY, SKIP, and LIMIT operations before you perform your pattern comprehensions:

```
WITH ru, u, childD, toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, toInt(sum(totalVotes)) as totalVotes, sortValue60640
ORDER BY  weight DESC,  totalVotes ASC, sortValue60640.value ASC, childD.createDate DESC 
  SKIP 0 LIMIT 100
RETURN ru, u, childD AS decision, weight, totalVotes, sortValue60640,
  [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(entity)<-[:COMMENTED_ON]-(comg:CommentGroup)-[:COMMENTED_FOR]->(childD) 
    | {entityId: id(entity),  types: labels(entity), totalComments: toInt(comg.totalComments)} ] AS commentGroups, 
  [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c1:Criterion)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg1:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_FOR]->(childD) 
    | {criterionId: id(c1),  weight: vg1.avgVotesWeight, totalVotes: toInt(vg1.totalVotes)} ] AS weightedCriteria, 
  [ (parentD)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch1:Characteristic)<-[:SET_ON]-(v1:Value)-[:SET_FOR]->(childD) 
    | {characteristicId: id(ch1),  value: v1.value, valueType: ch1.valueType, visualMode: ch1.visualMode} ] AS valuedCharacteristics
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Everything is working like a charm!